# Xamarin.Android: Cannot convert from "System.Collections.Generic.List<string>" to "[namespace_name].Item[]"

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, xaml, xamarin.android

I am trying to assign data received from external sql server to a `ListView`

(Xamarin.Android):

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listView3" />
```

The activity herefore looks like the following:

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.layout1);

        var lv = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView3);

        lv.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Item>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, Android.Resource.Id.Text1, BaseData.GetEmployees());
        lv.ItemClick += OnItemClick;
    }

    void OnItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        int position = e.Position; // e.Position is the position in the list of the item the user touched

        var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(DetailsActivity));

        intent.PutExtra("ItemPosition", position);

        StartActivity(intent);
    }
```

and the Get-Method is:

```
    public static List<String> GetEmployees()
    {
        List<String> list = new List<String>();

        string sql = "SELECT * FROM adressen";

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            con.Open();

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        list.Add(reader.GetString(0));
                    }
                }
            }

            con.Close();

            return list;
        }
    }
```

The column in the database contains simple strings.

Unfortunately I am getting the following error message from `BaseData.GetEmployees()` (Activity Line 8):

> Cannot convert from "System.Collections.Generic.List" to "GroceryList.Item[]".

Can anyone maybe tell me what the problem is and how to fix this, so the data from the database is displayed properly?

Thanks in advance for everything,

Best regards

Comment: What do you think that error means?

Comment: That I have strings and trying to put them into an object-list? or vice versa? something like that?

Comment: no answers at all?

thank you all very much, mod can close this topic